# Laravel error "Declaration of model/model_name should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model"

Tags: laravel, authentication, composer-php

i am facing a strange issue regarding laravel application. after updating the composer on my production server i am getting this error. My login page showing fine and when i am entering the credentials its showing this error either the credentials wrong or right its always showing the same error.

Error is

> Declaration of App\Models\User::update($a_data = NULL, $a_conditions = NULL) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update(array $attributes = Array, array $options = Array)

i have searched on internet but found nothing. Please do help. will be thankful.

Comment: You can't have an `update()` method in your User model. Laravel already has one in the base model class and that implements an interface.

Comment: Actually i am overriding that method. and it was working fine. and i think after updating my composer this issue occurs.

Comment: `update` requires an array as parameter try `App\Models\User::update([$a_data => NULL, $a_conditions => NULL])`

Comment: Nope.. Mike its throwing an syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When overriding a method from parent class - the signature of the method must be exactly the same in terms of parameters **and their types**

In the parent class, both `$attributes` and `$options` are set to be of type `array`, so you must also set set them this way in your class

```
namespace App\Models;

class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    ...
    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = []) {
       // ... your implementation
       return parent::update($attributes, $options);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yaron for your response. Just want to ask is it due to latest versions? 
because it was working fine. 

And now due to this change i need to change the my code like your mentioned in my all models.

Comment: What version do you use? and what is the version of `laravel/framework` in your `composer.json`. It doesn't seems like anything new

Comment: after updating user model like you mentioned now its showing me another error 

" Declaration of App\Models\General::increment($s_table = NULL, $a_condition = Array, $s_column = NULL) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = Array) "

Now its showing error one of my increment function.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your help. i did change 2 or 3 functions. now my application is back to work. Bundle of thanks.