# Problem with overwrite User3::all() method in User Mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a User Model as:

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use App\User;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
 use Notifications\EmailClientOfAccount;

class User3 extends User
{
use Notifiable;
public $emailList;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email',
];

public function __construct($emails)
{
    $this->emailList = $emails;

}

public  function getEmailList()
{
     return $this->emailList;
}
public static function all(array $columns=[])
{
    return $emailList;
}
public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
{
    return $this->email;
}
}
```

Then,and  in Controller:

```
$collection = collect([ 
[ 'name' => 'user1', 'email' => 'user1@gmail.com', ], [ 'name' => 'user2', 
'email' => 'user2@gmail.com', ], [ 'name' => 'user1000', 'email' => 
'user1000@gmail.com', ],
 ]);
```

Second Stage:
              $u4 = new User3($collection);
when I use :

```
dd($u4::all());
```

It show below error:
       ErrorException: Declaration of App\User3::all(array $columns = Array) 
       should be compatible with 
       Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all($columns = Array)

I very try for solve it, but dont,
very Thanks for any help to me,

Answer (score 0):

reference from: [Laravel error "Declaration of model/model_name should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427395/laravel-error-declaration-of-model-model-name-should-be-compatible-with-illumin)

When overriding a method from parent class - the signature of the method must be exactly the same in terms of parameters and their types

In the parent class, both $attributes and $options are set to be of type array, so you must also set set them this way in your class

```
namespace App\Models;

class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    ...
    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = []) {
       // ... your implementation
       return parent::update($attributes, $options);
    }
    ...
}
```

It show below error: ErrorException: Declaration of App\User3::all **(array $columns = Array)** should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all **($columns = Array)**
Check that potions. they are not same. May be this is the reason. focus on this may helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but My problem is in All method, and I test ($columns = Array)  but it has syntax error,